# gatsby-image getting props as undefined in the component

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm able to get the image data in GraphiQL but can't get to work in the component. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default function Landing({ data }) {
  console.log(data) // undefined
  return (
    <section id="landing" className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-around">
    </section >
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  {
    img: file(relativePath: {eq: "landing-women.jpg"}){
      childImageSharp{
        fluid{
          src
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

[image: GrapgiQL]

Comment: Do you need to put the word query before your opening brackets inside `graphql` string?

Comment: Tried that one too but it didn't work

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with your component not being in the 'pages' folder and so not being a page. Is that correct? Using page queries in components will cause the data to be undefined.

In gatsby you have [page queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/) (for pages), and [static queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/) (for components)

Comment: But it is working when imported as a seperate component which is also not in the pages folder right?

Comment: It works with a static query in a component. The graphql page queries will not work in components. In your solution you did use a static query.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would have a uniquely named query on each page component, otherwise I'm not sure whether Gatsby knows to extract it and pass it's resolved value as the data prop or not.

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default function Landing({ data }) {
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <section id="landing" className="d-flex flex-column justify-content-around">
    </section >
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query LandingQuery {
    img: file(relativePath: {eq: "landing-women.jpg"}){
      childImageSharp{
        fluid{
          src
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Tried it but didn't work..however it seems to work with useStaticQuery. when using it in a different component and then importing it

Comment: Do you get any errors in the terminal with the above solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know the exact reason behind it but, I did solve the issue by creating a seperate component for the image query and then importing it where required.

```
import React from "react";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image";
const Image = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
   query {
     img: file(relativePath: {eq: "landing-women.jpg"}){
       childImageSharp{
          fluid{
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_tracedSVG
          }
       }
     }
    }
  `)

return <Img className="img-fluid order-0 order-md-1 col-12 col-md-7" 
  fluid= {data.img.childImageSharp.fluid} />
}

export default Image
```